# Remove the site contents link on the quick launch sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to remove the site contents link in sharepoint site.can anyone having idea to delete the sitecontents link in sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this link,

Check the below link and click on SharePoint 2013 area which can help you.

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=226

You can also try below link..

http://mmman.itgroove.net/2013/06/26/how-to-remove-a-quick-launch-item-using-powershell/

http://sharepointryan.com/2013/04/15/fix-sharepoint-quick-launch-links-using-powershell/

Please mark Answer and Vote me if you think that it will help you

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS you can achieve this with below steps.

1. Navigate to page, edit the page
2. Add a Content Editor Web Part anywhere in the page.
3. place the below code

   > ```
   > <style> .ms-quicklaunchheader{
   > display:none;
   > }
   > </style>
   > ```
4. Click Save

Comment: this one also will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a code approach - I usually do that in an event receiver used for provisioning new sites:

```
var web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
var siteContents = pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNodes.OfType<SPNavigationNode>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Title == "Site Contents");
if (siteContents != null)
{
    pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNodes.Delete(siteContents);
}

pubWeb.Update();
```

Or if you have a custom web template, remove the following line from the ONET.xml:

```
<NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_SiteContents;" Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;" Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;" Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;" ID="1034" />
```

If it's a one time action and you are a site admin on a publishing site, just click on "Edit Links" and remove the link manually:
[image]

[image]